# Is there some math method to represent this kind of data?

Tags: algorithm

Suppose we have an array with cluster effect to some degree, such as

1 2 3 7 8 12 13 16 20 21 22 23

how do we represent this kind of data mathematically ?
If we have the other array like this

1 2 10 11 20 21

the intersection of these two array is

1 2 20 21

Noted that we are in the situation that we have an fully paralleled algorithm to calculate the intersection of two arrays of this kind, we want to analyze the cost in math convention. The algorithm is about binary search every element of the short array in the longer one.

We designed some algorithm for GPU, which is quite fast. We find that the algorithm is faster on the data with these kind of cluster effect. Now we want to analyze our algorithm on these kind of data, but we have no idea to do this.

Is there something like random process or
anything else can provide help to calculate the expectation of the cost ?

Comment: Your question is extremely vague. Are you trying to find an equation that will generate the sequence? A way of compressing the sequence? Something else? What do you mean by "this kind of data" or "cluster effect to some degree"? Or even "represent mathematically"? (A sequence of values is a mathematical representation.) Please edit your question so that the terms have a clear meaning.

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail? What are you doing with these numbers?

Comment: Thanks for the attention and sorry for my poor representation, please refer to the newly updated content.

Comment: Are both arrays always sorted?

Comment: yes, just like the posting lists of the search engine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by a fully paralleled algorithm, but since the arrays are sorted, you can do a sequential algorithm with time complexity O(m + n) where m and n are the array lengths:

```
int i = 0, j = 0;
while (i < array1.length && j < array2.length) {
    if (array1[i] == array2[j]) {
        add array1[i] to the intersection list
        ++i;
        ++j;
    } else if (array1[i] < array2[j]) {
        ++i;
    } else {
        ++j;
    }
}
```

This assumes that the arrays contain unique values. If a value might be repeated, the problem needs to be defined better as to what constitutes the intersection array.

The algorithm can probably be sped up quite a bit by doing a binary search instead of simply incrementing i or j when a match is not found. A binary search that reports where the element should be inserted when it is not found would be needed. (One that merely reports failure would be a waste of time.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We designed some algorithm for GPU, which is faster than the algorithm above. We find that the algorithm is faster on the data with these kind of cluster effect. Now we want to analyze our algorithm on these kind of data, but we have no idea to do this.

Comment: @xinli0 - Without knowing the details of your algorithm, it's difficult to say why clustering affects the execution time, much less quantify the effect.

Comment: We are not asking someone to do the analysis, we just want some clues or hints to do it. I do not even have the idea represent the effect.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the array and find the difference between every pair(0,1; 1,2; ...). Count the number of 1s and divide that by n-1. That'll give you the percentage of consecutive pairs. It's a primitive metric.

primitive_metric:

```
values = [1,2,3,4,5,8,9,10]  
values_length = 8  
consecutive = 0  
for i=0 to values_length - 1:  
    consecutive += ((values[i+1] - values[i]) == 1) ? 1 : 0
return consecutive/(values_length-1)
```